# Not Getting Windows as option to publish windows apps in WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I tried to publish windows apps in WSO2 EMM publish. But I am not getting windows as option in the publisher. Currently, I am using EMM 2.0 version. I cant find any config related to this. How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently WSO2 EMM 2.0.0 doesn't support windows app related features.So you could not able to publish windows apps and there are no any configurations related to the windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

I did add Windows phone compatibility in publisher, store.. You must write it by yourself.
You must edit the code of the publisher and Store and add the code related to windows devices like:

-Adding The compatibility of having a Windows file WSO2 Publisher

-Adding The compatibility of having a Windows file WSO2 Store

-Adding The Windows Store to install the files from the official website URL

-Check The link in Assets. GetURL

-Adding in the database to identify the Windows package in MDM

-Adding Windowsphone in the API Manager

-Modification Of affcihage

-Validation of .XAP and .Appx extentions.